# edit content in ruby on rails shopping cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I am trying to build a simple shopping cart with rails, now I am able to add products to cart, I want to know how can I edit products while they are in cart, I am using sessions to control the products in shopping cart. here is what the user see when add to cart :

```
<% @cart.items.each do |item| %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= image_tag item.pic , :alt => "#{item.title}" %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= link_to "#{item.title}" , store_path(item.product_id) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= item.unit_price %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= item.quantity %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= item.total_price %>
    </td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

and this is CartItem class :

```
class CartItem

  attr_reader :product, :quantity

  def initialize(product)
    @product = product
    @quantity = 1
  end

  def increment_quantity
    @quantity += 1
  end

  def product_id
    @product.id
  end

  def title
    @product.name
  end

  def pic
    @pic = @product.photo.url(:thumb)
  end

  def unit_price
    @product.price
  end

  def total_price
    @product.price * @quantity
  end

end
```

I want to give the user this ability to edit the quantity of products or remove a product, not only clear the whole cart. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already have something setup in a close manner.  You have the increment_quantity method within your cart item model, so what you would need to do is setup the cart model to allow you to specify a product, and then call a new method, like so:

cart.rb (assuming this is your cart model)

```
def increment_product_quantity(id, quantity)
   product_to_increment = @items.select{|product| product.product_id == id}

   # We do this because select will return an array
   unless product_to_increment.empty?
      product_to_increment = product_to_increment.first
   else
      # your error handling here
   end

   product_to_increment.quantity = quantity
end

def remove_product(id)
   @items.delete_if {|product| product.product_id == id }
end
```

Now, you will have to modify your cart item model to where quantity is not an attr_reader object, but an attr_accessor object, or create a method for cart items specifically to where you set the quantity; your choice.

There are a few other things which could be done, but this is roughly the easiest and cleanest method that I can recommend right now.

Comment: Would I need to add a new controller action (i.e. Edit_Cart)? Or does it make more sense to add the edits on my add_to_cart action?

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question. I was able to get the delete function to work. It looks like you are following the pragmatic programmers [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails), Third Edition book.

Here we go...

**To add_to_cart.html.erb**

I added the following table row, beside the last tr line item:

```
<td><%= link_to 'remove', {:controller => 'inventories', :action => 'remove_cart_item', :id => "#{item.getinventoryid}"} %></td>
```

**To CartItem.rb model**

changed attr_reader :inventory, :quantity to `attr_accessor :inventory, :quantity`

```
def getinventoryid
   @inventory.id
end
```

**To Cart.rb model:**

changed attr_reader :items to `attr_accessor :items`

```
def remove_inventory(inventory)
   @items.delete_if {|item| item.inventory == inventory }
end
```

**To inventories_controller.rb:**

```
def remove_cart_item
  inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
  @cart = find_cart
  @cart.remove_inventory(inventory)
  redirect_to_index("The item was removed")
 end
```